# Log all program console output to file on demand

Tags: java, logging

I have a task to implement a logging method that will take all program content up to logging method call and save it to file. The method should not overwrite already present info in file, but rather add new content to it.

What I need to write:

- all program messages and output;
- all user inputs in the way they appear on console (the program inquires it several times);

My thought on it is to create a StringBuilder object and start appending everything to it. Once logging method is invoked, ask for a file to save log to and save contents of StringBuilder to it. Then flush StringBuilder and continue to gather information. On second invocation, if the same filename is provided, just append new info gathered by StringBuilder.

However, this means that I will need to place gathering invocations all over the place where program output and user input are. Seems like not very optimal to me.

Are there any ideas on how to reach my goal differently and more optimally?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Vadim

UPDATE: I actually was able to redirect system.out to gather everything to ByteArrayStream and then write to file on demand. But I still don't understand how to do it for inputstream. I don't need to redirect it, I still have to input eveyrthing from keyboard, it's just values that have to make it to logs in correct places. Am still searching for a solution.

Comment: you can change the `System.in`,  `System.out` and `System.err` to add the logging to the corresponding extended `InputStream` and `PrinterStream`

Comment: and will it preserve console output, if I redirect System.out to different place? Thank you.

Comment: that is the meaning of "extended" in previous comment: the corresponding stream must log in parallel to its default operation (similar to the `tee` command on unix)

Comment: Thank you, will have to do my research, since it's not something I've done before.

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Go for a logging framework. There is one [integrated into java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/core/java-logging-overview.html#GUID-B83B652C-17EA-48D9-93D2-563AE1FF8EDA) anyway.
Alternatively you can use [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/index.html), and there are other such frameworks out there.

Comment: Probably I have to. I'm taking courses and we haven't still dealt with logging frameworks and logging in general. Therefore I think I have to use whatever we've learnt at this point.

Comment: Just redirect stdout. Continue to use System.out.println() or whatever. Here is an example: https://github.com/paulwedeck/settlers-remake/blob/master/jsettlers.logic/src/main/java/jsettlers/main/JSettlersGame.java#L382

Comment: Thank you. I need to double outputs to StringBuilder and to console and inputs as well. Will look into it.